# How to auto link URLs in outlook emails?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007

When I compose an email in Outlook 2007, it does not auto link URL's like it used to, which is kind of annoying.

Anyone know the setting to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it took me a while to find it, but this is where the setting is at in Outlook 2007

1. Tools menu...
2. Options...
3. Mail Format Tab
4. "Editor Options..." button at the bottom
5. Then click the "Proofing" button on the left
6. Then select the "AutoCorrect Options..." button
7. Select the "AutoFormat As You Type" tab
8. Look for a check box called "Internet and network paths with hyperlinks" in the first section
9. Check/unckeck it as you wish.

Comment: Yep, this works for me as well. It's a shame that it's a whole 8 clicks away just to check the box.

Comment: Ya, outlook's settings are pretty disorganized.  they really need to revamp them.

Comment: From your best bud.